# Get data from each array of array with sequence output

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, underscore.js

i am trying to get sequence index of each array of array like I have an element of the array and that 5 arrays have multiple elements and I want to get the first index of each array then the second and so.

below is my array data

```
const arrData = [[1,2,4,6],[3,8,7],[12,13],[],[9,10]];
```

and my expected outout `[1,3,12,9,2,8,13,10,4,7,6]`

give me some sort of solution to fix my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try my below solution may be it will fix your

```js
let data = [[], [], [1, 2, 4, 6], [8, 9, 10], [], [12], [14, 15], []], index = 0;
data = data.filter(o => o.length != 0)
const result = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].length > index) {
        index = data[i].length
    }
    if (data[i].length > 0) {
        for (j = 0; j < index; j++) {
            if (data[j][i] != undefined) {
                result.push(data[j][i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log("Result", result);
```

Comment: Congratulations on your first answer! Do keep in mind that you add some details about what you fixed or why it is right. It helps users understand what is going on, rather than just being served the answer. Consider this an absolute rule for all your answers here.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually work for other cases. Example - change `[1, 2, 4, 6]` to `[1]`, and result would be `[1, 9, 10]`.

Answer (score 1):

Following might work:

```js
const src = [[1,2,4,6],[3,8,7],[12,13],[],[9,10]],

      pickByOne = arr => {
        const result = [],
              {length} = arr.flat()
        while(result.length < length){
          for(a of arr){
            a.length && result.push(a.shift())
          }
        }
        return result
      }
      
console.log(pickByOne(src))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [zip](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zip) from `lodash`. Since the function takes a sequence of arguments and you have an array, you'll need to spread the array with `...`

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const arrData = [[1,2,4,6],[3,8,7],[12,13],[],[9,10]];
const z =  _.zip(...arrData)
```

This will give you the following result:

```
[
  [ 1, 3, 12, undefined, 9 ],
  [ 2, 8, 13, undefined, 10 ],
  [ 4, 7, undefined, undefined, undefined ],
  [ 6, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
]
```

You can already see it's in the order that you want. Now to clean things up. You can use `flatMap` in its simplest form to flatten the array.

```
// lodash
const fm = _.flatMap(z)

// or with Array.prototype.flat()
const fm = z.flat()
```

This will give you a single array.

```
[
  1,         3,         12,
  undefined, 9,         2,
  8,         13,        undefined,
  10,        4,         7,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  6,         undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined
]
```

Now you just need to remove all the `undefined` elements by filtering (keeping) all the elements that are not `undefined`.

```
// lodash
_.filter(fm, _.negate(_.isUndefined))
```

and you have your final result.

```
[1, 3, 12, 9, 2, 8, 13, 10, 4, 7, 6]
```

There are many ways to solve this issue so you'll need to decide based on your particular case and balance simplicity, code legibility, efficiency, etc.

Comment: Use `_.reject(fm, _.isUndefined)` instead of `_.filter(fm, _.negate(_.isUndefined))`

Answer (score 1):

Find the longest length of the sub-array using `Array.map()` to get the length of all sub-arrays, and `Math.max()`. Use `Array.from()` to create an array with the length of the longest length. For each index in the created array, use `Array.flatMap()` to get all items from the original sub-arrays. If the item is `undefined`, use the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to substitute it with an empty array, which `Array.flatMap()` would ignore when flattening the resulting array. Flatten the output of `Array.from()` using `Array.flat()` to get a single array.

```js
const fn = arr =>
  Array.from({ length: Math.max(...arr.map(o => o.length)) }, (_, i) => 
    arr.flatMap(o => o[i] ?? [])
  ).flat();

const arrData = [[1,2,4,6],[3,8,7],[12,13],[],[9,10]];

const result = fn(arrData);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to keep track of the `index` which defines the position of the elements to get in each iteration.
- Use a `while` loop that would terminate when there are no remaining elements in any of the arrays at a certain `index`.
- Use [`.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) to get a list of elements in each array at the index
- Remove `undefined` elements in this list using [`.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter) in case one of the arrays has no element at an index
- Use [`.isEmpty`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEmpty) to check if this list is empty, then, terminate

```js
const arrData = [[1,2,4,6],[3,8,7],[12,13],[],[9,10]];

let res = [], index = 0;

while(true) {
  const elementsAtIndex = _.filter(
    _.map(arrData, e => e[index]), 
    e => e!==undefined
  );
  if(_.isEmpty(elementsAtIndex)) break;
  res = [...res, ...elementsAtIndex];
  index++;
}

console.log(...res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I don't understand the part with _.without and _.isEmpty and _.map what is this underscore syntax?

Comment: @Alex I added more clarifications

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a nested array, you can loop through and check if the first element of each nested array is undefined or not. If no, you can push it into the result array. I wrote the function for your ref. Please check

```
 const arrData = [[1, 2, 4, 6], [3, 8, 7], [12, 13], [], [9, 10]];
    function sorter(arr) {
  var result = [];
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].length > 0) {
        if (arr[i][0] !== undefined) {
          result.push(arr[i][0]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(sorter(arrData));
```

I hope this is what you expected! Please reach me if you need clarification.

Comment: Have you tried it out? This will absolutely not work

Answer (score 0):

Simple one without any operator whould look like....

```
    const ipArr = [ [1, 2, 4, 6], [8, 9, 10], [], [12], [14, 15], [] ]
    let maxLength = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < ipArr.length; i++) {
        if (ipArr[i].length > maxLength) maxLength = ipArr[i].length
    }
    const opArr = []
    for (let j = 0; j < maxLength; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < ipArr.length; k++) {
            if (ipArr[k][j]) opArr.push(ipArr[k][j])
        }            
    }
    console.log('opArr = ', opArr)
```